# Angular JS ng-model not initiating properly for the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using Angular JS ng-model to track the selected value of the select tag.

here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/8853oxb1/3/

```
function ControllerA($scope) {
    $scope.optionsArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope.optionsObject = {"India" : "IN" , "Singapore" : "SG", "Malaysia" : "MY", "Indonesia" : "INDY"};

}
```

If, I go to a dropdown by using a tab key and try to press "I" twice to select the second option starting with I, the dropdown value updates as expected, bu the ng-model just takes the value of the first option with "I". A bug in angular js or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Use `$scope.chosenO = $scope.optionsArray[0];` for default first selection

Comment: My aim is not to get the first selection, I want to get the values of the one that shows up on the frontend. It happens if we use manually open the dropdown too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8853oxb1/30/)

The main difference with your code is the way the dropdown is built.

Instead of feeding it with a single object

```
$scope.optionsObject = {"India" : "IN" , "Singapore" : "SG", "Malaysia" : "MY", "Indonesia" : "INDY"};
```

you have to change your data into something different, for instance, an array of object, like this:

```
$scope.optionsObject = [ { name: "India", code: "IN" }, { name: "Singapore", code: "SG" }, { name: "Malaysia", code: "MY" }, { name: "Indonesia", code: "INDY" } ];
```

Comment: this thing works, but how come the one i've done doesn't work? Now I have to change a lot of implementation.. :|